# Header color issue The Events Calendar - Avada theme

Tags: wordpress

The header color on The Events Calendar is white on mobile and medium screen view instead of black (as seen on full screen).

Here is the page with the issue

https://www.heritagecentralotago.org.nz/events/

I am using the Avada theme
Your help is much appreciated

I have tried using custom css

Answer (score 0):

Add below the CSS in your style.css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px){
    .fusion-body .fusion-header-wrapper .fusion-header, .fusion-body .fusion-header-wrapper .fusion-secondary-main-menu {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
}
```